# How to replace field with substring after specific character in SQL?

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have a field in a SQL table with the format "XXX/NAME" and I would like to replace the value and to keep only the character after "/" which means that "XXX/NAME" should become "NAME". How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Take a look at the documentation https://mariadb.com/kb/en/string-functions/. Might find some functions that could help.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to remove 'XXX/' then you can use `replace()`

```
 select replace('XXX/NAME','XXX/','')new_value
```

Output:

| new_value |
| --- |
| NAME |

If you want to keep everything after '/' in a string then `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` is your answer.

```
 select SUBSTRING_INDEX('XXX/NAME','/',-1) new_value
```

Output:

| new_value |
| --- |
| NAME |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=fabaa82fe5871f8ee4fd4a287b2a046a)*